# My JavaScript button runs only if I don't edit the field's content first

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to make a javascript button that can delete all the spaces in a HTML form field.

It only works once if I don't type inside the field first.
I cant figure why.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <textarea id="gcode" name="gcode" rows="20" cols="100"placeholder="Write your GCODE here...">N100 G20
N102 G0 G17 G40 G49 G80 G90
N104 G91 G28 Z0</textarea>
    <div><input type="button" value="Spaces" onclick="spaces();"></div>
</form>

<script>
function spaces() {
  var str = document.getElementById("gcode").innerHTML;
  var replaced = str.split(' ').join('');
  document.getElementById("gcode").innerHTML=replaced;
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: textarea elements don't have any innerHTML, use *value*.

Comment: You are right !!! Thanks. It works changing  **.innerHTML** to **.value**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use value instead

```html
<script>
  function spaces() {
    var str = document.getElementById("gcode").value;
    var replaced = str.split(' ').join('');
    document.getElementById("gcode").value=replaced;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try take the value of textarea input
     `str = document.getElementById("gcode").value;`
     `document.getElementById("gcode").value=replaced;`

Comment: There are 2 lines that have to be changed.